# create single login for multiple domains with automatically increase other domain session time as user refresh first one

Tags: cross-domain, single-sign-on

I would like to know how to manage single login for multiple domains. I search for hours and read several articles and got many new things. I really impressed with one of this answer

[How to create a Shared Login Service across Multiple Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306728/how-to-create-a-shared-login-service-across-multiple-domains/4575720#4575720)

But One thing is could not cleared in this.

Suppose my login site (domain) is checklogin.com and I want to use it for two domains domain1.com and domain2.com. I applied logic for login suggested by above link.

My problem is that I made a login on domain1.com through checklogin.com and verify that login from domain1.com to checklogin.com using socked (curl) API. After confiming login user keep surfing  on domain1.com for around 30 minuts. My Website session timeout is 20 minutes but session on domain1.com does not expire as session refreshes every time when user click a link on domain1.com.

After 30 minutes user jumps from domain1.com to domain.com. In this case domain2.com will redirect user to checklogin.com as domain2.com does not recognize user sessio but session on checklogin.com has already expired because of 20 Minute session time. So user have to fill login detail again.

I don't want to call webservice from domain1.com to checklogin.com everytime user visit any link on domain1.com as I will increase overhead on checklogin.com.

Please suggest what would be the efficient solution for this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the session timeout for 20 min on domain1.com and domain2.com
2. Set the session timeout for 30 min on checklogin.com
3. Each request on domain1.com (or domain2.com) execute curl to checklogin.com to renew a session on checklogin.com
4. Therefore when you will access other application at domain2.com (or domain1.com) the session will be active.

Comment: Thanks for very quick answer!
The 3rd step is time consuming as at every user request on domain1.com or on domain2.com need to communicate with cecklogin.com. And it will create burden on checklogin.com as other domains will always hit checklogin.com on every user request.

Comment: You can do it for example, each 1 min. Any case, many Identity Managent system (like Siteminder) do similar process on each request. Otherwise you can find a flow when the session on checklogin.com is expired.