# passing login form information one website to another website's login page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have Internet service. They provide Login page for internet Login (Ex: i.e. http://globalNetSolutions.com/Login.html). If i am buying one website (Ex : i.e. http://MyNetSolutions.com/Login.html) is it possible to From my website username & password to http://globalNetSolutions.com/Login.html website (because of that 3rd party site not looking grate.i want login from my own website.)

I changes are needed where do i change my code :

```
<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="">
    <h2>LOGIN TO <span class="red"><strong>MyNetSolutions</strong></span></h2>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="choose a username...">

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="choose a password...">
    <button type="submit">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Not sure about javascript, but yes you can share your login session accross domains in php.

Comment: You may be looking for Federation with SAML

Comment: Use a Single Sign On (SSO).
Explained here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342378/cross-domain-login-how-to-login-a-user-automatically-when-transferred-from-one][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342378/cross-domain-login-how-to-login-a-user-automatically-when-transferred-from-one

Comment: Thanks @Oscar Bout & Jijo Mathew,  i will try with above solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use oauth for lo-gin purpose. But problem with that is you can not use user password for encryption. Id you do not care about that, then you can go ahead with oauth approach.