# Allow access to site only from link on other site

Tags: .htaccess

I want to allow access to a site outside the company, only via a link on the company site via .htacces configuration on 'www.myside.com'. The code below work to bring me to the site but my CSS, JPG, PNG, JS is not loaded.

```
<If "%{HTTP_REFERER} != 'https://www.CompanySite.com'">
Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</If>
```

What should be added/changed to make the site load all scripts etc?

Comment: I would not do this as the `HTTP_REFERER` can be faked

Comment: How would you do it?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342378/cross-domain-login-how-to-login-a-user-automatically-when-transferred-from-one)

Comment: That looks like a solid solution, but I've no control over the company website. I can only put a link on a page.